# Weird behavior of Blender in Docker vs on my system

Tags: python, rendering, linux

I have the following BPY script:

```py
import bpy
import addon_utils

addon_utils.enable("io_import_images_as_planes")

class AddGroundPlane(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = 'tdm.add_ground_plane'
    bl_label = 'Add Ground Plane'
    bl_options = {"REGISTER", "UNDO"}
    
    size: bpy.props.FloatProperty(name="Size")
    color: bpy.props.FloatVectorProperty(
        name="Color",
        subtype="COLOR",
        size=4,
        min=0.0,
        max=1.0,
        default=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
    )

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(size=self.size)
        plane = bpy.context.active_object

        new_mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name="plane")
        new_mat.diffuse_color = self.color
        plane.data.materials.append(new_mat)
    
        return {"FINISHED"}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(AddGroundPlane)

def unregister():
  bpy.utils.unregister_class(AddGroundPlane)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
    bpy.ops.tdm.add_ground_plane(size=100, color=(0.7, 0.65, 0.35, 1))
```

I run it using the following command:

```bash
blender -b --python path/to/my/script.py -o path/to/output/render -f 1
```

If I run it directly on my computer, which has the following Blender version installed (I remember it working with earlier versions as well):

```
Blender 3.2.1
        build date: 2022-07-05
        build time: 23:53:28
        build commit date: 2022-07-05
        build commit time: 15:44
        build hash: a2d59b2dac9e
        build platform: Linux
        build type: release
        build c flags:  -Wall -Wcast-align -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=return-type -Werror=vla -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wno-char-subscripts -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wpointer-arith -Wunused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wlogical-op -Wundef -Winit-self -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wno-div-by-zero -Wtype-limits -Wformat-signedness -Wrestrict -Wnonnull -Wabsolute-value -Wuninitialized -Wredundant-decls -Wshadow -Wno-error=unused-but-set-variable -Wimplicit-fallthrough=5  -std=gnu11 -msse -pipe -fPIC -funsigned-char -fno-strict-aliasing -ffp-contract=off -msse2 -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0  
        build c++ flags:  -Wuninitialized -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wno-invalid-offsetof -Wno-sign-compare -Wlogical-op -Winit-self -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wno-div-by-zero -Wtype-limits -Werror=return-type -Wno-char-subscripts -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wpointer-arith -Wunused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wundef -Wformat-signedness -Wrestrict -Wno-suggest-override -Wuninitialized -Wundef -Wmissing-declarations -Wimplicit-fallthrough=5  -msse -pipe -fPIC -funsigned-char -fno-strict-aliasing -ffp-contract=off -msse2 -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0  
        build link flags:  -Wl,--version-script='/home/blender/git/blender-v320/blender.git/source/creator/blender.map'
        build system: CMake
```

then it works as expected: the script executes first, then the render happens.

---

However, when I try to do the same in a Docker container using the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16

COPY . /opt/app
WORKDIR /opt/app/services/tdm-backend

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -yqq blender

CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev" ] # a script that runs the same command as above
```

It works in a weird way: first, it renders the scene, but only then it executes the script. On top of that, the script runs unsuccessfully:

```
tdm-backend_1  | ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
tdm-backend_1  | ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
tdm-backend_1  | ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
tdm-backend_1  | ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
tdm-backend_1  | ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
tdm-backend_1  | ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
tdm-backend_1  | ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
tdm-backend_1  | ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
tdm-backend_1  | AL lib: (EE) ALCplaybackAlsa_open: Could not open playback device 'default': No such file or directory
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:16.18M (0.00M, Peak 16.18M) | Time:00:00.00 | Preparing Scene data
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:16.19M (0.00M, Peak 16.19M) | Time:00:00.00 | Preparing Scene data
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:16.19M (0.00M, Peak 16.19M) | Time:00:00.00 | Creating Shadowbuffers
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:16.19M (0.00M, Peak 16.19M) | Time:00:00.00 | Raytree.. preparing
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:16.19M (0.00M, Peak 16.19M) | Time:00:00.00 | Raytree.. building
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:16.21M (0.00M, Peak 16.22M) | Time:00:00.00 | Raytree finished
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:16.21M (0.00M, Peak 16.22M) | Time:00:00.00 | Creating Environment maps
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:16.21M (0.00M, Peak 16.22M) | Time:00:00.00 | Caching Point Densities
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:16.21M (0.00M, Peak 16.22M) | Time:00:00.00 | Sce: Scene Ve:8 Fa:6 La:1
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:16.21M (0.00M, Peak 16.22M) | Time:00:00.00 | Loading voxel datasets
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:16.21M (0.00M, Peak 16.22M) | Time:00:00.00 | Sce: Scene Ve:8 Fa:6 La:1
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:16.21M (0.00M, Peak 16.22M) | Time:00:00.00 | Sce: Scene Ve:8 Fa:6 La:1
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:16.21M (0.00M, Peak 16.22M) | Time:00:00.00 | Volume preprocessing
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:16.21M (0.00M, Peak 16.22M) | Time:00:00.00 | Sce: Scene Ve:8 Fa:6 La:1
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:16.21M (0.00M, Peak 16.22M) | Time:00:00.00 | Sce: Scene Ve:8 Fa:6 La:1
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.21M (0.00M, Peak 17.69M) | Time:00:00.00 | Scene, Part 2-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.65M (0.00M, Peak 18.14M) | Time:00:00.01 | Scene, Part 4-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.67M (0.00M, Peak 18.17M) | Time:00:00.01 | Scene, Part 6-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.63M (0.00M, Peak 18.17M) | Time:00:00.01 | Scene, Part 7-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:18.02M (0.00M, Peak 18.19M) | Time:00:00.02 | Scene, Part 1-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.94M (0.00M, Peak 18.19M) | Time:00:00.02 | Scene, Part 8-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:18.02M (0.00M, Peak 18.19M) | Time:00:00.03 | Scene, Part 3-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:18.02M (0.00M, Peak 18.27M) | Time:00:00.03 | Scene, Part 10-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:18.35M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.03 | Scene, Part 5-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:18.24M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.03 | Scene, Part 12-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:18.24M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.03 | Scene, Part 14-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:18.15M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.03 | Scene, Part 9-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:18.06M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.03 | Scene, Part 16-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.97M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.03 | Scene, Part 17-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.54M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.03 | Scene, Part 11-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.54M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.03 | Scene, Part 19-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.99M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.04 | Scene, Part 20-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.90M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.04 | Scene, Part 21-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.81M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.04 | Scene, Part 15-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.72M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.04 | Scene, Part 23-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.42M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.04 | Scene, Part 24-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.38M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.04 | Scene, Part 22-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.58M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.04 | Scene, Part 25-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.42M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.04 | Scene, Part 26-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.42M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.04 | Scene, Part 28-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.42M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.04 | Scene, Part 29-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.42M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.05 | Scene, Part 18-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.81M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.05 | Scene, Part 27-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.72M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.05 | Scene, Part 32-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.60M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.05 | Scene, Part 33-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.51M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.05 | Scene, Part 34-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.81M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.05 | Scene, Part 35-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.72M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.05 | Scene, Part 31-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.67M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.05 | Scene, Part 37-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.49M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.05 | Scene, Part 36-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.88M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.05 | Scene, Part 38-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.58M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.05 | Scene, Part 39-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.42M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.05 | Scene, Part 41-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.42M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.05 | Scene, Part 40-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.20M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.05 | Scene, Part 42-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.58M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.05 | Scene, Part 43-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.20M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.05 | Scene, Part 44-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.38M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.05 | Scene, Part 45-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.20M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.05 | Scene, Part 47-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.12M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.05 | Scene, Part 46-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.74M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.05 | Scene, Part 30-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.68M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.05 | Scene, Part 49-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.37M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.05 | Scene, Part 51-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.52M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.05 | Scene, Part 50-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.42M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.05 | Scene, Part 52-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.42M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.05 | Scene, Part 53-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.52M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.05 | Scene, Part 54-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.37M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.05 | Scene, Part 56-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.37M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.05 | Scene, Part 57-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.12M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.05 | Scene, Part 55-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.12M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.05 | Scene, Part 59-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.12M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.06 | Scene, Part 60-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.58M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.06 | Scene, Part 61-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.12M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.06 | Scene, Part 58-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.42M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.06 | Scene, Part 62-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.44M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.06 | Scene, Part 13-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.10M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.06 | Scene, Part 64-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.25M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.06 | Scene, Part 63-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.34M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.06 | Scene, Part 66-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.46M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.06 | Scene, Part 67-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.29M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.06 | Scene, Part 69-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.29M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.06 | Scene, Part 68-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.26M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.06 | Scene, Part 70-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.29M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.06 | Scene, Part 65-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.45M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.06 | Scene, Part 72-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.29M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.06 | Scene, Part 71-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.26M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.06 | Scene, Part 74-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.25M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.06 | Scene, Part 76-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.20M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.06 | Scene, Part 75-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.25M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.06 | Scene, Part 73-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.20M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.06 | Scene, Part 78-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:16.90M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.06 | Scene, Part 79-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.20M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.06 | Scene, Part 81-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.20M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.06 | Scene, Part 80-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.20M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.06 | Scene, Part 82-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.25M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.06 | Scene, Part 77-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.35M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.06 | Scene, Part 84-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.61M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.06 | Scene, Part 83-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.24M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.06 | Scene, Part 85-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.61M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.06 | Scene, Part 87-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.24M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.06 | Scene, Part 88-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.43M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.06 | Scene, Part 89-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.39M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.06 | Scene, Part 91-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.43M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.06 | Scene, Part 92-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.44M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.06 | Scene, Part 48-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.43M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.07 | Scene, Part 93-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.13M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.07 | Scene, Part 94-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.44M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.07 | Scene, Part 96-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.43M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.07 | Scene, Part 95-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.13M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.07 | Scene, Part 97-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.44M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.07 | Scene, Part 98-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.43M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.07 | Scene, Part 99-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.13M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.07 | Scene, Part 100-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.44M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.07 | Scene, Part 102-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.36M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.07 | Scene, Part 101-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.41M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.07 | Scene, Part 90-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.45M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.07 | Scene, Part 104-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.19M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.07 | Scene, Part 105-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.31M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.07 | Scene, Part 106-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.25M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.07 | Scene, Part 107-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.45M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.07 | Scene, Part 108-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.29M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.07 | Scene, Part 110-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.29M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.07 | Scene, Part 109-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.29M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.07 | Scene, Part 86-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.29M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.07 | Scene, Part 112-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.29M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.07 | Scene, Part 111-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.29M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.07 | Scene, Part 114-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.81M (0.00M, Peak 18.65M) | Time:00:00.07 | Scene, Part 113-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:18.28M (0.00M, Peak 19.00M) | Time:00:00.08 | Scene, Part 116-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:18.19M (0.00M, Peak 19.00M) | Time:00:00.08 | Scene, Part 117-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:18.10M (0.00M, Peak 19.00M) | Time:00:00.08 | Scene, Part 118-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:18.01M (0.00M, Peak 19.00M) | Time:00:00.08 | Scene, Part 119-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.93M (0.00M, Peak 19.00M) | Time:00:00.08 | Scene, Part 120-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.84M (0.00M, Peak 19.00M) | Time:00:00.08 | Scene, Part 121-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.75M (0.00M, Peak 19.00M) | Time:00:00.08 | Scene, Part 122-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.66M (0.00M, Peak 19.00M) | Time:00:00.08 | Scene, Part 124-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.62M (0.00M, Peak 19.00M) | Time:00:00.08 | Scene, Part 123-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.53M (0.00M, Peak 19.00M) | Time:00:00.08 | Scene, Part 125-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.48M (0.00M, Peak 19.00M) | Time:00:00.08 | Scene, Part 127-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.40M (0.00M, Peak 19.00M) | Time:00:00.08 | Scene, Part 103-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.31M (0.00M, Peak 19.00M) | Time:00:00.08 | Scene, Part 128-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.22M (0.00M, Peak 19.00M) | Time:00:00.08 | Scene, Part 126-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.13M (0.00M, Peak 19.00M) | Time:00:00.08 | Scene, Part 131-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:17.04M (0.00M, Peak 19.00M) | Time:00:00.08 | Scene, Part 132-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:16.95M (0.00M, Peak 19.00M) | Time:00:00.08 | Scene, Part 130-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:16.86M (0.00M, Peak 19.00M) | Time:00:00.08 | Scene, Part 134-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:16.82M (0.00M, Peak 19.00M) | Time:00:00.08 | Scene, Part 133-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:16.73M (0.00M, Peak 19.00M) | Time:00:00.08 | Scene, Part 135-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:16.69M (0.00M, Peak 19.00M) | Time:00:00.08 | Scene, Part 129-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:16.38M (0.00M, Peak 19.00M) | Time:00:00.09 | Scene, Part 115-135
tdm-backend_1  | Fra:1 Mem:15.97M (0.00M, Peak 19.00M) | Time:00:00.09 | Sce: Scene Ve:8 Fa:6 La:1
tdm-backend_1  | Saved: '/opt/app/services/tdm-backend/geometry-6622890658855882/render0001.png'
tdm-backend_1  |  Time: 00:00.18 (Saving: 00:00.08)
tdm-backend_1  | 
tdm-backend_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
tdm-backend_1  |   File "/opt/app/services/tdm-backend/src/blender/paperback/operators.py", line 39, in <module>
tdm-backend_1  |     bpy.ops.tdm.add_ground_plane(size=100, color=(0.7, 0.65, 0.35, 1))
tdm-backend_1  |   File "/usr/share/blender/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py", line 189, in __call__
tdm-backend_1  |     ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
tdm-backend_1  | TypeError: Converting py args to operator properties: : keyword "size" unrecognized
tdm-backend_1  | 
tdm-backend_1  | Blender quit
```

I tried the following Blender versions: `2.79` and `3.1.2`

Is there any way to fix it? I would love to know the reason for this difference in behavior and how to make Blender in Docker work as expected? Thanks.

---

Edit: here is how I managed to install a newer Blender version correctly:

```
FROM ubuntu:focal

COPY . /opt/app
WORKDIR /opt/app/services/tdm-backend

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -yqq software-properties-common ca-certificates apt-transport-https curl
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:savoury1/ffmpeg4
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:savoury1/blender
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -yqq blender
# RUN blender -v

RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -yqq nodejs

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it, because v3.0.1 provided in the PPA is not the latest version. However, it fixes the problem for me.

Since snaps don't work in Docker (to my knowledge), if anyone knows a good way to get the latest Blender version, I would be grateful if you post it in the comments.

Edit 2: v3.0.1 seems to be working much slower in Docker than on my system. So, I installed v3.2.1 using a tarball, and now the behavior of Blender is identical both in Docker and on bare metal.

```
FROM ubuntu:focal

WORKDIR /opt/blender
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -yqq wget xz-utils libx11-6 libxi6 libxxf86vm1 libxfixes3 libxrender1 libgl1
RUN wget https://mirrors.dotsrc.org/blender/blender-release/Blender3.2/blender-3.2.1-linux-x64.tar.xz
RUN tar -xJvf blender-3.2.1-linux-x64.tar.xz

RUN wget -qO - https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -yqq nodejs

COPY . /opt/app

WORKDIR /opt/app/services/tdm-backend

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

Comment: i was able to reproduce your problem. i verified that when i run `npm run dev` directly from the terminal it calls the latest version of blender and it works. can you try? but when i run `docker run` then `npm` will run the old blender version 2.79 and thus fail because the syntax for operator variables is different in older version.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Thanks a lot for your comment. This is indeed the case. I tried again to install a higher Blender version in Docker (3.0.1), and it started working. If you want, please feel free to post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: wow! i'm glad it worked out! i was scratching my head over this for a while until i included the context and printed out the blender version and then i realized it was the operator syntax that failed!

Comment: may I ask what your updated Dockerfile looks like.

Comment: I edited my question to include the new Dockefile. Thank you once again for the help.

Comment: cool thanks! yes snap doesn't work with docker, its very complicated to setup with docker as far as my reading goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are **2 issues** here.

**Issue 1** is the `$PATH`. I verified that when you run `npm run dev` directly from the terminal it calls the latest version of blender correctly and it works but if you execute `docker run` then `npm` will use a different `$PATH` and will execute the old blender version 2.79 which will ofcourse fail when it executes the python script because the syntax for operator variables is different. An update to the latest version and update to the $PATH pointing to the right blender version will rectify issue 1.

**Issue 2** is the context. As with many of the `bpy.ops` operations you need to pass the proper context using an override. Here is the working script:

```
import bpy
import addon_utils
from bpy.props import FloatProperty, FloatVectorProperty

addon_utils.enable("io_import_images_as_planes")

win = bpy.context.window
scr = win.screen

class AddGroundPlane(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = 'tdm.add_ground_plane'
    bl_label = 'Add Ground Plane'
    bl_options = {"REGISTER", "UNDO"}
    
    size: FloatProperty(name="")
    color: FloatVectorProperty(
        name="Color",
        subtype="COLOR",
        size=4,
        min=0.0,
        max=1.0,
        default=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
    )

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(size=self.size)
        plane = bpy.context.active_object

        new_mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name="plane")
        new_mat.diffuse_color = self.color
        plane.data.materials.append(new_mat)
    
        return {"FINISHED"}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(AddGroundPlane)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(AddGroundPlane)

# ========================================================================================
#
# Starting in 3.2 context overrides are deprecated in favor of temp_override
# https://docs.blender.org/api/3.2/bpy.types.Context.html#bpy.types.Context.temp_override
#
# They are scheduled to be removed in 3.3
#
# ========================================================================================

def use_temp_override():
    ''' Determine whether Blender is 3.2 or newer and requires
        the temp_override function, or is older and requires
        the context override dictionary
    '''
    version = bpy.app.version
    major = version[0]
    minor = version[1]
    print("VERSION ===", major, "===", minor, "version=", version)
    return not (major < 3 or (major == 3 and minor < 2))

def get_areas(type):
    return [area for area in scr.areas if area.type == type]

def get_regions(areas):
    return [region for region in areas[0].regions if region.type == 'WINDOW']

def execute():

    areas  = get_areas('VIEW_3D')

    if use_temp_override():

        with bpy.context.temp_override(window=win, area=areas[0], regions=get_regions(areas)[0], screen=scr):

            bpy.ops.tdm.add_ground_plane(size=100, color=(0.7, 0.65, 0.35, 1))

    # ========================================================================================
    # (else) execute using legacy override
    # ========================================================================================        

    else:
        override = {
            'window': win,
            'screen': scr,
            'area': areas[0],
            'region': get_regions(areas)[0],
        }

        bpy.ops.tdm.add_ground_plane(override, size=100, color=(0.7, 0.65, 0.35, 1))
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
    print("EXE3")
    execute()
```